# Question in the past perfect and answer using "would"

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, present-perfect, grammaticality-in-context

I have this question from the university that I am applying to:

> Why have you chosen this type of mobility?

my answer is:

> I would prefer to study a degree seeking mobility rather than exchange
>   mobility because I would have enough ....

is it correct to use `would` even when the question is past perfect?

#### For those who have asked what is "mobility"

There are two types of mobility which are exchange and degree seeking.
The exchange means that the university where I will study my master's degree, will send a student to the university where I am currently studying for my bachelor's degree.

The degree seeking means that I will pay the fees of the master. And no student will go back to my current university.

```
These are eurabean types
```

Answer (score 2):

These terms are new to me,  but a little Googling suggests that what you select is not *exchange mobility* or *degree-seeking mobility* but an exchange or degree-seeking *mobility program* or *mobility scheme*. Since "scheme" can in some contexts be a little negative, I think you are better off using "program", as [this site](http://www.efrei.fr/en/programs-international-students#.UtsU1dLnb4Y) does.

A couple of ways to say this might be:

> I have chosen a degree-seeking rather than an exchange mobility program because ... *This echoes the actual question, "Why have you chosen ... "*.
>
> I prefer the degree-seeking to the exchange mobility program because ... *This preserves your own word* prefer. *I suggest dropping the* would *because your preference is not contingent on being accorded a choice; and in any case the form of the question implies that you are to answer as if you **have already made** your choice*.

Comment: See my comment below the OP's question. I believe the "degree seeking" is *work experience program*. I'm not sure how this is called in the US or in Europe, but at least it makes sense. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think you can either stay with a host family or rent a room within the university campus. As for the "tironcino" program I don't think that is abroad, but it may well mean the student has to change city. I'm sorry, but I don't have any direct experience with any of this.

Comment: Oh, I know that the degree is awarded at the university where you attend. The Erasmus program is whereby students from different universities in different countries swap /do an exchange. This can be a period lasting as little as three months or up to one year. It's called *Erasmus* in Italian, I have no idea if the same term is used in the rest of Europe, I would imagine so.

Answer (score 2):

Verbs that follow **prefer**, *love*, *like*, or *dislike* can take either the gerund or the infinite.
For more information, see the ELU question:[When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive/330#330)
Hence in the case of *prefer* either form is acceptable :

I prefer **studying**
I prefer **to study**

To avoid repeating the same noun twice in the same sentence use the pronoun, one.

[**one and ones**](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/one-and-ones)

We use one (singular) and ones (plural) to avoid unnecessary repetition.

> - See those two girls? Helen is the tall **one** and Jane is the short **one**.
> - Which is your car, the red **one** or the blue **one**?
> - My trousers are torn.
>     I need some new **ones**.

Therefore I would advise the OP to write

> <del>I **would prefer** to participate in the student mobility placement (SMP) program rather than the SM Erasmus exchange **one** because...</del>

### **EDIT**

The question asks:

> Why have you chosen this type of mobility?

Therefore the OP SHOULD reply using the *present perfect*:

I **have chosen** the student mobility placement [(SMP)](http://www.programmallp.it/index.php?id_cnt=280) program because...

It is unnecessary to add `rather than XXX` because the question is not asking why you *preferred* one program over another, the OP has already made his decision.

In addition, the auxiliary *would* is inappropriate in this case. `I would prefer to XXX` is used to express what you want to do or wish you could do in a polite manner in the *present* and NOT in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The question is **present perfect**.

However, yes, `would` is fine in this case provided you haven't yet started the course, since you're referring to it conditionally (that is, when/if you are accepted).

If it were the case that you had been accepted, the question would likely be:

> Why **did you choose** this type of mobility?

And your answer:

> I wanted to study a degree....

Comment: Thanks for answering. also, for your comment on the question. the sentence becomes `I would prefer to study a degree in seeking mobility rather than exchange mobility ` is it possible to replace `exchange mobility` with `exhcnage onec` or `exchange one` or what please?